# I got json from googlespreasheet and i need to pass some variables to js function

Tags: javascript, ajax, getjson, google-sheets-api

```
$.getJSON(url, function(json) {
  for (var i in json) {
    if (json[i].emaill == userMail) {
      role = data[i].role
    }
  }
  return role
});
```

i need to pass role variable to the another function

Comment: `$.getJSON` is async.

Comment: yes , i know but how do i handle it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: great , i wasnt thinking about that , i was trying to calculate values with javascript but i couldve easily passed case to googlescript and gs calculate it and return response ... dummy me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$.getJSON(
    url,
    [data],
    [callback]   //Do what u want
)
Process the role in callback

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of where you want the data, you first need to understand how javascript handles asynchronous code (and what that means for YOU, the developer) Because [$.getJSON](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) is asynchronous, doing something like `return role` will not do anything useful in your regular idea of how functions return values. Something introduced recently is [await/async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) which attempts to abstract away a lot of this code. However, this also comes with some caveats. What I would do is use async/await to make things a lot more simple. I would use fetch:

```
async function getUserRole (userEmail) {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const json = await response.json();
  let role;
  json.forEach(user => {
    if(user.email === userEmail) {
      role = user.role;
    }
  }
  return role;
}
```

Because of the `await` keyword before the `fetch` and `response.json()` the javascript engine will not move onto the next line even though these are asynchronous calls. This makes the code behave more like you would expect. Then after we get the json data, we can iterate over each element with the array function `forEach` and set the role based on the passed in `userEmail`. Do note however, that you see the `async` declaration before the function? That is required anytime you use await. This means that you will also need to decorate the function that is calling `getUserRole` with `async` as well.